# how to insert row in SQL database in ADO.Net Connection oriented mode

Tags: sql, ado.net

I have a database in which a table has name `Registration` which is used to register the user.

It has only two column one is `Username` and one is `password`.

A page named `Register.aspx` is used for registering the member which have two textbox one is for taking `Username(textbox1)` and one is for taking `password(textbox2)` and one button for insert these value in database.

The Main problem is that we cannot write statement like this :

```
Insert into Registration (Username, password) 
values ('TextBox1.text','TextBox2.text')
```

I am using ADO.net Connection oriented mode, I googled but I didn't find any way to insert row in SQL database in connected mode. Please provide me a idea for inserting this row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADO.NET has DataReader which supports Connected mode. All else are disconnected.

> DataReader is connected architecture since it keeps conneection open untill all records are fetched

If you want to insert in ADO.NET then you should perform the following steps:

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
   //create  object  of Connection Class..................
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

   // Set Connection String property of Connection object..................
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=KUSH-PC;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated           Security=True";

 // Open Connection..................
  con.Open();

 //Create object of Command Class................
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

//set Connection Property  of  Command object.............
cmd.Connection = con;
//Set Command type of command object
//1.StoredProcedure
//2.TableDirect
//3.Text   (By Default)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//Set Command text Property of command object.........

cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Registration (Username, password) values ('@user','@pass')";

//Assign values as `parameter`. It avoids `SQL Injection`
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", TextBox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", TextBox2.text);

 Execute command by calling following method................
  1.ExecuteNonQuery()
       This is used for insert,delete,update command...........
  2.ExecuteScalar()
       This returns a single value .........(used only for select command)
  3.ExecuteReader()
     Return one or more than one record.

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();


  MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");          
  }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
     }


    }
```

Comment: Right, teach young padavans how to leak resources and leave a never closing connections. Also, try to show example from your tribesman below how to close connections only after exception.

Comment: @ArtemG never closing connection?

Comment: @syedmohsin you fixed post, added con.close() in catch and not only and  try to ask making big surprised eyes? )))  Date of my comment -  15.11.2013, last edited - 2.04.2015. Good try, but no.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try
        {

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
            {
                string queryString = "Select id, name, age from Table where name = @name";
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

                    Connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        item = new Item(long.Parse(dataReader[0].ToString()),
                                        dataReader[1].ToString(),
                                        int.Parse(dataReader[2].ToString()));
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // if exception will happen in constructor of SqlConnection or Command, the // resource can leak but Dispose method will never be called, couse the object was not created yet.        

          // Trace and handle here
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
```

But ADO.net is useless for enterprice development. You have to have and abstraction from Data Acess Layer and go to entities, not table records
Use the ORM, Luke!

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string cnstr = "server=.;database=dbname;user=username;password=password;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = con };
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Registration (Username, password) values ('@user','@pass')";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", TextBox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", TextBox2.text);
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //something;
}
finally
{
    if (con != null)
       con.Close();
}
```

Comment: haha :) u r right @Artem, I was on a rush so I made it fast :) I'm Iranian by the way, Not Indian. Code corrected. thanks.